# How do I detect multi-touch in cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, multi-touch

*Edited Post*

Ok I tried what rptwsthi said in another project just to test it......

```
-(id) init
{
if( (self=[super init])) {

    self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
}
return self;
}

- (void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    NSArray *touchArray=[touches allObjects];

    if ([touchArray count] == 2) {
        NSLog(@"touch 2");
    }
    else if([touchArray count]==1) {
        NSLog(@"touch 1");
    }
}
```

But only the "touch 1" NSLog pops ups when I press the screen with two fingers. Do I need to put what LearnCocos2D said in there somewhere too.

*Old Post*

I have a test app I'm making and in it I have 3 buttons in the hud, 2 are for moving left and right and the other is for shooting. This is what I currently have.....

```
-(void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint loc = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
loc = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:loc];

//Move Left
CGRect left = CGRectMake(leftButton.position.x-50/2, leftButton.position.y-50/2, 50, 50);
if (CGRectContainsPoint(left, loc)) {
    [self schedule:@selector(moveLeft)]; 
}

//Move Right
CGRect right = CGRectMake(rightButton.position.x-50/2, rightButton.position.y-50/2, 50, 50);
if (CGRectContainsPoint(right, loc)) {
    [self schedule:@selector(moveRight)];
}

//Shoot
CGRect shoot = CGRectMake(shootButton.position.x-50/2, shootButton.position.y-50/2, 50, 50);
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(shoot, loc)) {
    bullet = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bullet.png"];
    bullet.position = ccp(plane.position.x, plane.position.y+20);
    [self addChild:bullet];
    }
}

-(void) ccTouchesEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self unschedule:@selector(moveLeft)];
    [self unschedule:@selector(moveRight)];
}
```

But I can only press one button at a time. I want to be able to hold the right or left button and also shoot with the shoot button. Can anyone fix my code or show me a basic example of multi-touch?

Also I'm new to iOS development and any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Just use `allObject` instead of `anyObject`, and check it like:

```
- (void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    NSArray *touchArray=[touches allObjects];

    if ([touchArray count] == 2)
        //DO ONE THING 
    else if([touchArray count]==1)
        //DO ANOTHER THING
}
```

Comment: refer [this link..](http://www.qcmat.com/dragging-multiple-sprites-in-cocos2d/)  this will help you for more

Answer (score 5):

Have you enabled multiple touches on the cocos2d view?

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector].openGLView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
```

Comment: Sorry, but where do I put this? I not sure what file is the cocos2d file.

Comment: you can call this method anywhere, ie in the init method of your scene or in the app delegate's applicationDidFinishLaunching method.